# What is an smap in clojure?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

In clojure documentation the term `smap` is occasionally used. For example, [core/replace](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/replace):

> Given a map of replacement pairs and a vector/collection, returns a
>   vector/seq with any elements = a key in smap replaced with the
>   corresponding val in smap.

What is meant by the term "`smap`"?

Comment: Try `(find-doc "smap")` in a REPL to see more examples.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no special meaning. It's just referring to the name of the parameter of the function:

```
(replace smap coll)
```

It seems plausible that "smap" stands for "substitution map".

They might have prefixed it with an "s" so it doesn't shadow the [built-in used inside the function](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L4998), or because they considered the use case of the map parameter to be specific enough to warrant a more specific name.

Comment: You're not wrong, but the "problems" would be pretty minor: the body could just use clojure.core/map instead of map.

Comment: @amalloy That's true. It seemed odd though that they'd use a different name for the parameter and call it something as ambiguous as "smap", when plain `map` is used in many other places. I'll edit it in a sec.